# UITableView - View in custom cell xib not being hidden independently from other cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I have an UITableView with custom cells (custom cell xib). This custom cell xib, contains another xib that has some views that need to be hidden according to the data bound to the cell.
When hiding a view in a cell, the views in all cells are hidden.

Is this behavior standard? Is there a way to hide a label in just one cell?

**EDIT**

UITableView *cellForItemAtIndexPath* method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
CellBasic *cell = (CellBasic *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellBasic" forIndexPath:indexPath];


cell.title.text = currentItem.title;
cell.genre.text = currentItem.genre;

[cell.viewExtraInfo setDetails:(currentItem.format.length > 0) ? currentItem.format : NULL
                          type:(currentItem.type != nil) ? currentItem.type : NULL
                        rating:NULL];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnItem:)];
[cell.viewExtraInfo.viewFormatBadge addGestureRecognizer:tap];
cell.viewExtraInfo.viewFormatBadge.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.viewExtraInfo.viewFormatBadge.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

return cell;
}
```

Each cell in the table view contains a child xib (*viewExtraInfo*) that also contains a horizontal UIStackView with three views, each with three labels (viewTypeBadge - labelType, viewFormatBadge - labelFormat, viewRating - labelRating).

The *setDetails* method (in *viewExtraInfo*) called by the table view on each cell:

```
- (void) setDetails:(NSString*) format
         type:(NSString*) type
          rating:(NSString*) rating {


if (type){
    self.labelType.text = type;
} else {
    self.viewTypeBadge.hidden = YES;
}

if (format){
    self.labelFormat.text = format;
} else {
    self.viewFormatBadge.hidden = YES;
}

if (rating) {
          self.labelRating.text = rating;
} else {
    self.viewRating.hidden = YES;
}
```

When hiding *viewFormatBadge* in one cell, the view is hidden in all other cells.

Comment: You need to show some of your code, probably your cellForRow function along with how you are configuring your custom cell in it's own class. Otherwise the problem could be from a number of things

Comment: @AlanS please see my edit. Thank you!